Hosting coturn in AWS via Docker results in relay address always being private
We're running coturn in the following environment:

EC2 on a public subnet with a public and private interface
coturn running in Docker, via AWS ECS

Notably, we do not have an load balancer or NAT gateway in front of this instance. We have opened the security groups to allow all ports from all IPs.
When I test our instance via Trickle ICE, I get the following:
0.072   srflx   3   udp x.x.x.x         52931   100 | 32287 | 255       
0.077   relay   5   udp 10.53.34.156    65525   5   | 32285 | 255       
0.089   srflx   3   udp x.x.x.x         65047   100 | 32287 | 254       
0.097   relay   5   udp 10.53.34.156    65501   5   | 32285 | 254   

Where x.x.x.x is correctly my public IP. However, the relay endpoint is the private IP from within our Docker container. My understanding of ICE is that this should be a public interface so that clients can use it for TURN sessions.
Here are our launch configs and startup commands:
0: (1): INFO: log file opened: /var/log/turn_1_2024-04-22.log
0: (1): INFO: System cpu num is 2
0: (1): INFO: System enable num is 1
0: (1): INFO: Listener address to use: 0.0.0.0
0: (1): INFO: Relay address to use: 0.0.0.0
0: (1): INFO: Coturn Version Coturn-4.6.2 'Gorst'
0: (1): INFO: Max number of open files/sockets allowed for this process: 1048576
0: (1): INFO: Due to the open files/sockets limitation, max supported number of TURN Sessions possible is: 524000 (approximately)
0: (1): INFO: 

==== Show him the instruments, Practical Frost: ====

0: (1): INFO: OpenSSL compile-time version: OpenSSL 3.1.4 24 Oct 2023 (0x30100040)
0: (1): INFO: TLS 1.3 supported
0: (1): INFO: DTLS 1.2 supported
0: (1): INFO: TURN/STUN ALPN supported
0: (1): INFO: Third-party authorization (oAuth) supported
0: (1): INFO: GCM (AEAD) supported
0: (1): INFO: SQLite supported, default database location is /var/lib/coturn/turndb
0: (1): INFO: Redis supported
0: (1): INFO: PostgreSQL supported
0: (1): INFO: MySQL supported
0: (1): INFO: MongoDB supported
0: (1): INFO: Default Net Engine version: 3 (UDP thread per CPU core)
0: (1): INFO: Domain name: 
0: (1): INFO: Default realm: gearbox.com
0: (1): ERROR: CONFIG: Empty cli-password, and so telnet cli interface is disabled! Please set a non empty cli-password!
0: (1): INFO: Certificate file found: /etc/coturn/cert.pem
0: (1): INFO: Private key file found: /etc/coturn/private-key.pem
0: (1): INFO: TLS cipher suite: ALL:!COMPLEMENTOFDEFAULT:!eNULL:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
0: (1): INFO: DTLS cipher suite: ALL:!COMPLEMENTOFDEFAULT:!eNULL:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
0: (1): INFO: pid file created: /var/run/turnserver.pid
0: (1): INFO: IO method: epoll (with changelist)
0: (1): INFO: RFC5780 disabled! /NAT behavior discovery/
0: (1): INFO: Wait for relay ports initialization...
0: (1): INFO:   relay 0.0.0.0 initialization...
0: (1): INFO:   relay 0.0.0.0 initialization done
0: (1): INFO: Relay ports initialization done
0: (1): INFO: Total General servers: 2
0: (14): DEBUG: turn server id=1 created
0: (13): DEBUG: turn server id=0 created
0: (1): INFO: Total auth threads: 3
0: (15): INFO: SQLite DB connection success: /var/lib/turn/turndb
0: (1): INFO: prometheus collector disabled, not started

Our startup command:
sudo docker run -d -v /root/config/turnserver.conf:/etc/coturn/turnserver.conf \
                   -v /root/ssl/private-key.pem:/etc/coturn/private-key.pem \
                   -v /root/ssl/cert.pem:/etc/coturn/cert.pem \
                   --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/var/lib/coturn \
                   --network=host \
                   -p 3478-3479:3478-3479 -p 3478-3479:3478-3479/udp \
                   -p 443:443 -p 443:443/udp \
                   -p 65500-65535:65500-65535/udp \
                   -e DETECT_EXTERNAL_IP=yes \
                   -e DETECT_RELAY_IP=yes \
                   coturn-gbx \
                   --min-port=65500 \
                   --max-port=65535 \
                   --no-multicast-peers \
                   --no-tlsv1 --no-tlsv1_1 \
                   --realm=company.com

Question: Should our relay endpoint be public? If so, what are we doing wrong?
